# Separate date and time in Excel

Tags: excel, date, datetime, time, excel-formula

I need to separate the date and time for a large list of data in Excel, the format is **12/23 1600** (i.e. 23 December 16:00). 
I tried the function **=DATE(YEAR(serial_number),MONTH(serial_number),DAY(serial_number))**, but it couldn't read that format.

Could you please tell me how to do that without change the format?

Comment: You won't be able to get the year from that date format.  Excel will treat it as text - `=serial_number+1` returns a #VALUE error.  You'll have to use text functions to pull the various parts out and then feed it into the DATE function - `=LEFT(serial_number,FIND("/",serial_number)-1)` will return the 12, `=MID(serial_number,FIND(" ",serial_number)+1,LEN(serial_number))` will return the time part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me as I see your data

```
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),LEFT(A2,2),MID(A2,4,2))
```

and

```
=TIME(INT(MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1,9)/100),MOD(MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1,9)/100,1)*100,0)
```

Comment: As long as the format is always the same - **01/08 0730** for example rather than **1/8 730**.

Comment: @Bob - yes it works, thank you very much. I noticed that function returns the year to 2016, is that the default value as we're in 2016?

Answer (score 1):

If the data is a string, **AND IF** your windows short date regional format is MDY, then try:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1))
```

If the data is a "real" date, formatted to appear as you show, then try:

```
=INT(A1)
```

In either case, be sure to format the result as you desire.

If your Windows regional settings are other than MDY, then you can use this more complex formula:

```
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1)-1),MID(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1),FIND("/",A1)+1,2))
```

For the time portion, you can try

```
=TIMEVALUE(REPLACE(RIGHT(A1,4),3,0,":"))
```

If the above does not work, then provide more information about exactly what is in the cell, your regional format, etc.

Comment: I was about to say I stand corrected from my answer - but yours returns 1st December 2023, which may be what the OP is after.  I think they're after 23rd December of some unknown year though.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook  As I wrote, for mine to work requires that your Windows Regional setting be MDY.  I'm guessing yours is DMY, as that would produce the result you show.

Comment: Point taken.  Will equate to `=DATEVALUE("12/23")` which is 23rd December 2015 in MDY.

Comment: I tried to merge these two functions =DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),LEFT(A2,2),MID(A2,4,2)) and =TIME(INT(MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1,9)/100),MOD(MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1,9)/100,1)*100,0) to apply them on this cell 01/21 0501 , so I did the following : =DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),LEFT(A2,2),MID(A2,4,2))+TIME(INT(MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1,9)/100),MOD(MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1,9)/100,1)*100,0) , it is supposed to get 1/21/2016 5:01 , but I got just 1/21/2016 , Would you please check this and tell me what's the error?

Comment: It works fine here.  I will guess that you did not properly format the cell to show time as well as date.